# while loop not working properly

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The result is something like this:

1. You hit enemy for 8 damage enemy has 92 hp left
2. Enemy hit you for 8 damage you have 86 hp left
3. You hit enemy for 5 damage enemy has 81 hp left
4. Enemy hit you for 11 damage you have 72 hp left
5. You hit enemy for 12 damage enemy has 67 hp left
6. Enemy hit you for 7 damage you have 60 hp left
7. You hit enemy for 13 damage enemy has 40 hp left
8. Enemy hit you for 11 damage you have 32 hp left
9. You hit enemy for 2 damage enemy has 33 hp left
10. Enemy hit you for 15 damage you have 16 hp left
11. You hit enemy for 15 damage enemy has 2 hp left
12. Enemy hit you for 17 damage you have -11 hp left

You died: -11 hp Enemy wins!

Enemy hp is: -8 You win! You gain 50 exp!

Both has 100 hp and as you can see on row 2, there is one "loop" missing out as enemy hit 8 damage and 86 hp is left.

Also how to stop the loop when one of them dies so that both cant die at the same time? So that if one dies the loop stops and determines the winner.

Is there a better way to determine the started from random?

```
<?php

$p_hp = 100;
$p_atk = 20;
$p_defence = 5;

$m_hp = 100;
$m_atk = 20;
$m_defence = 5;

if ($p_hp > 0) {

    $turn = rand(0,1);
    $hitnr = 0;

    while (($p_hp >= 0) && ($m_hp >= 0)) {

        $turn--;
        $hitnr++;

        $enemydef = $p_atk - $m_defence / 2;
        $my_damage = rand(1, $enemydef);

        $playerdef = $m_atk - $p_defence / 2;
        $enemy_damage = rand(1, $playerdef);

        $p_hp = $p_hp - $enemy_damage;
        $m_hp = $m_hp - $my_damage;

        // Player turn
        if ($turn % 2 == 0) {
            echo "<b>".$hitnr.".</b> Enemy hit you for  <font color='red'><b>".$enemy_damage . "</b></font> damage you have <b>".$p_hp." hp</b> left<br>";    

        // Monster turn    
        } else {
            echo "<b>".$hitnr.".</b> You hit enemy for  <font color='green'><b>".$my_damage . "</b></font> damage enemy has <b>".$m_hp." hp</b> left<br>";
        }

        if ($p_hp <= 0) {
            echo "<br>You died: ".$p_hp." hp<br><font color='red'><b>Enemy wins!</b></font>";
         }

        if ($m_hp <= 0) {
            echo "<br>Enemy hp is: ".$m_hp."<br><font color='green'><b>You win! You gain 50 exp!</b></font>";

        }
    }
} else {
    echo "You are dead. <a href='hospital.php'>Go to the hospital!</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: If it's player turn - then moster hp should reduce and vice versa, now for each turn you reduce both characters hp.

Comment: Check both hit-points for negative numbers, if one passes as true, then break the statement `if ($EnemyHealth < 0 OR $PlayerHealth < 0){ break; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless monsters (or players) can counterattack, only the target's HP should decrease:

```
$p_hp = 100;
$p_atk = 20;
$p_defence = 5;

$m_hp = 100;
$m_atk = 20;
$m_defence = 5;

if ($p_hp >= 0) {

    $turn = rand(0,1);
    $hitnr = 0;

    while (($p_hp >= 0) && ($m_hp >= 0)) {

        $turn--;
        $hitnr++;

        $enemydef = $p_atk - $m_defence / 2;
        $my_damage = rand(1, $enemydef);

        $playerdef = $m_atk - $p_defence / 2;
        $enemy_damage = rand(1, $playerdef);

        // Monster turn
        if ($turn % 2 == 0) {
            $p_hp = $p_hp - $enemy_damage;
            echo "<b>".$hitnr.".</b> Enemy hit you for  <font color='red'><b>".$enemy_damage . "</b></font> damage you have <b>".$p_hp." hp</b> left<br>";    

        // Player turn    
        } else {
            $m_hp = $m_hp - $my_damage;
            echo "<b>".$hitnr.".</b> You hit enemy for  <font color='green'><b>".$my_damage . "</b></font> damage enemy has <b>".$m_hp." hp</b> left<br>";
        }

        if ($p_hp <= 0) {
            echo "<br>You died: ".$p_hp." hp<br><font color='red'><b>Enemy wins!</b></font>";
         }

        if ($m_hp <= 0) {
            echo "<br>Enemy hp is: ".$m_hp."<br><font color='green'><b>You win! You gain 50 exp!</b></font>";

        }
    }
} else {
    echo "You are dead. <a href='hospital.php'>Go to the hospital!</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: This helped but i had to change
while (($p_hp >= 0) && ($m_hp >= 0)) {
to
while (($p_hp > 0) && ($m_hp > 0)) {
Cause if someone hit 0 it would loop out 3 times like this
You died: 0 hp
Enemy wins!32. You hit enemy for 5 damage enemy has 4 hp left

You died: 0 hp
Enemy wins!33. Enemy hit you for 13 damage you have -13 hp left

You died: -13 hp
Enemy wins!